# Meaning of $(W,X)\perp (Y,Z)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, independence

I know $X\perp Y$ means $X$ is independent of $Y$, and $(W,X)\perp Y$ implies $W\perp Y$, $X\perp Y$, but what does 
$$
(W,X)\perp (Y,Z)
$$
mean?

My guess is that it means 
$$
\begin{align}
W&\perp Y & W&\perp Z\\
X&\perp Y & X&\perp Z
\end{align}
$$
but we would not have $W\perp X$, $Y\perp Z$, $W\perp (Y,Z)$ or $X\perp (Y,Z)$?

Is this correct?

Comment: We have all this but all this does not imply the condition you started from. Say, do you have a definition of independence of vectors of random variables at hand?

Comment: @Did Ahh, independence of marginals does not imply joint independence. That is, $W\perp Y$ and $W\perp Z$ doesn't imply $W\perp (Y,Z)$. I have edited the post, please let me know if it is correct now (or if I misunderstood what you said).

Comment: Again, the condition $$(W,X)\perp (Y,Z)$$ implies all of the conditions $$W\perp Y\quad  W\perp Z\quad X\perp Y\quad X\perp Z\quad W\perp (Y,Z)\quad X\perp (Y,Z)$$ but al these conditions together do not imply that $$(W,X)\perp (Y,Z)$$

Comment: @Did Alright. Thanks for always answering the questions I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would mean $P(W,X,Y,Z)=P(W,X)P(Y,Z)$. If you marginalize out you would get what you are claiming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I think I can perhaps prove it (albeit inelegantly)
Consider $X$ and $Y$, and let $f_i$ denote the pdf (possible joint) of $i$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y} &= \int_W\int_Z f_{W,X,Y,Z}dz dw &&= \int_W\int_Z f_{W,X}f_{Y,Z}dz dw\\
&= \int_Wf_{W,X}\int_Z f_{Y,Z}dz dw &&=\int_W f_{W,X}f_Y dw\\
&=f_Y\int_W f_{W,X} dw &&= f_Yf_X
\end{align}
$$
which means they are independent

Apologies for poor formatting